# How to check if my Linux Box installation installation has SSE instructions capabilities?

Tags: c++, linux, sse, simd, libjpeg

How to check if my Linux Box installation installation has SSE instructions capabilities?

I am trying to install libjpeg-turbo and I want to make sure that it fully utilizes the capabilities of my box.

Answer (score 6):

Use `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep sse` to see if your CPU has SSE abilites.

Comment: 22:flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow nonstop_tsc pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8legacy 3dnowprefetch ts fid vid ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps
46:flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow nonstop_tsc pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8legacy 3dnowprefetch ts fid vid ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps

Comment: The _sse_ and _sse2_ extensions are available.

Comment: Availability doesn't mean package uses SSE.

Comment: You're right, I clarified my answer. Still, the original question was "how to check if the extension is available".

Answer (score 0):

To show all the CPU flags:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```